# Are all modern currencies based on decimals?

Tags: decimal, currency

Are all/most modern currencies (mainly used in international business) based on the decimal system.

for example there are 100 pence in a pound, 100 cent in a euro and 100 cent in a dollar.

Is this the same for all currencies major business currencies? (I think it is, im just double checking)

Comment: This isn't really programming related - maybe it would be better on some other StackExchange site.

Comment: its for an online finance system written in PHP :P

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd say this is a pretty safe assumption. According to [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-decimal_currency):

> Today only two countries in the world use non-decimal currencies. These are Mauritania (1 ouguiya = 5 khoums) and Madagascar (1 ariary = 5 iraimbilanja).